# ReactJS: css transition not working in componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

When the `EffectBox` component is mounted, I want to add a `show` `class` to this component. But css transition doesn't work.

This is js code:

```
 var EffectBox = React.createClass({
   componentDidMount: function () {
     this.show();
     // setTimeout(this.show, 100);
    },

    show: function () {
      $(React.findDOMNode(this)).addClass('show');
    },

    render: function () {
      return (
        <div className="effect-box" >
        <div className="header"></div>
        <div className="content">
        ...
       )
    }
  });
```

Css as follow:

```
.effect-box {  
  transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  transition: all .4s;
}

.show {
  transform: none;
}
```

And when I use a `delay` to call show `function(use setTimeout)`, the css animation works. At this point `(componentDidMount)`, did the real DOM get rendered?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on my own React project with following code, which seems to work just fine:

```
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.show();
  },

  show: function() {
    React.findDOMNode(this).classList.add('show');
  }
```

and:

```
.show {
  transition: transform 400ms;
  transform: translate3d(-200px, -200px, 0px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've met this problem and I've found a couple solutions:

One that I prefer more is to wrap `this.show()` in `requestAnimationFrame` (It's gently version of timeout.)

```
componentDidMount: function () {
     requestAnimationFrame(()=> {this.show();});  
 }
```

Second one is very rude but if you don't want to use any kind of timeout you can trigger relayout. It may harm application performance.

```
componentDidMount: function () {
  document.body.offsetHeight;
  this.show();  
}
```

Comment: This works for me, but I was curious as to what is happening here. Could you clarify what the problem is please?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of a fixed timeout, try waiting for document ready inside componentDidMount:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        this.show();
    });
}
```

Comment: jQuery has nothing to do with this.

Comment: The OP's show() function is calling a jquery method, addClass, on a jquery object! How can you say jquery has nothing to do with jquery? That's nonsense.

Comment: True, I didn't notice the (unnecessary) usage of jQuery. However it's not a components responsibility to listen whether the whole document has been rendered. And when we're dealing with Single Page App and Virtual DOM, that jQuery event will be executed only once - not necessarily when we render (update) the component into view.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you're saying, and you are correct.