# ReactJS transition for progress bar not working

Tags: css, reactjs

I am just diving into ReactJS so I am quite a newbie in this Reactjs world. I have read the FB documentations and some tutorials on the internet and started my test project.

In my test project I am trying to include a progress bar for users to see their progress of filling down some forms across 3 pages. This part works all great till I wanted to add some transition magic to the process bar.

I've written the code below and I thought it would be the right way to archive my goal by pushing a prop from the parent to this child progressBar component for determining the percentage of the progress bar.

In my constructor I set the default width at 0 to update it by componentDidMount to a percentage which comes from the parent. I've managed to receive and set te style but the transition isn't working at all. I try to archive a fancy progress bar which runs from 0% width to the given width in percentage via the props.

My code look likes as follow:

**ProgressBar component**

```
import './style.scss';
import React from 'react';
import classnames from 'classnames';

class ProgressBar extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { progressionStyle : { } }
}
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
        progressionStyle : {
            width : this.props.progression,
            transition : 'all 1500ms ease'
        },
        scene1 : (this.props.scene1 == 'active') ? 'active' : (this.props.scene1 == 'done')   ? 'done' : '',
        scene2   : (this.props.scene2   == 'active') ? 'active' : (this.props.scene2 == 'done')     ? 'done' : '',
        scene3 : (this.props.scene3 == 'active') ? 'active' : (this.props.scene3 == 'done')   ? 'done' : '',
    });
}
/**
 *
 * Render
 * @return {JSX}
 */
render() {
    return (
        <div className="progress-bar">
            <div className="progress-bar__inner">

                <div className="progress-bar__progress">
                    <div className={classnames('progress-bar__progress-fill', this.props.active)} style={this.state.progressionStyle}></div>
                </div>

                <div id="scene1" className="progress-bar__element">
                    <i className={classnames('progress-bar__icon', this.state.scene1)}></i>
                    <span className="progress-bar__label">Scene 1</span>
                </div>

                <div id="scene2"  className="progress-bar__element">
                    <i className={classnames('progress-bar__icon', this.state.scene2)}></i>
                    <span className="progress-bar__label">Scene 2</span>
                </div>

                <div id="scene3" className="progress-bar__element">
                    <i className={classnames('progress-bar__icon', this.state.scene3)}></i>
                    <span className="progress-bar__label">Scene 3</span>
                </div>

            </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default ProgressBar;
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set the nested state directly, you should be doing it like

```
componentDidMount() {
  var style = {...this.state.style}

  style.width = this.props.progression
  style.transition =   'all 500ms ease-in' 

  this.setState({style});
}
```

Also, you need to update your state in the `componentWillReceiveProps` function as you are updating state based on the props.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  var style = {...this.state.style}

  style.width = nextProps.progression
  style.transition = 'all 500ms ease-in' 

  this.setState({style});
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, actually it works great to set a nested state as it's the same as you're writing in the end? Can you explain why not and where it's defined in the documentation? Besides, the transition seems to work now but in the wrong direction. When I go back in screens via route it works but going up front, transition doesn't work (width works)

Comment: It worked because you were setting a new object which contains transtition and width to state, however a better way is to do as I did above, you can see the immutability helpers documentation https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html . are youo sure you are using componentWillReceiveProps too

Comment: Yes, tried exactly your code and transition works but just when I navigate back.. :/

Comment: When I remove the componentDidMount function with only the componentWillReceiveProps function it works but I have to click twice to get the progression filling up the bar

Comment: Try and use the componentWillMount function instead of componentDidMount

Answer (score 0):

To make this effect work, I've found out the solution was to wrap the style into a function and call via request animation frame via as fol

```
 componentDidMount() {
        requestAnimationFrame(()=> {
            this.showProgress();
        });
    }

    showProgress() {
        var style = { };
        style.width = this.props.progression;
        style.transition = 'all 1500ms ease-in';
        this.setState({style});
    }
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43779273/968898